# Using MODIS Terra TIF file to get land-water map

Tags: matlab, image-processing, arcgis, satellite-image, envi

- I am able to read the modis image into Matlab. And I want to do some simple calculations. But, how do I access the different bands in Matlab?
- So, I have downloaded the 7-2-1 tif data (Not HDF) from the MODIS website and I want to create a map that shows flooded and non-flooded regions. I would like to do ISODATA classification in Matlab (And also in ArcGIS or ENVI). So far I have read the data into both ArcGIS and Matlab. But I am not able to use the different bands (7-2-1).

But I am not sure how to proceed.

This is an example MODIS image: http://lance-modis.eosdis.nasa.gov/imagery/subsets/?subset=USA6.2013323.terra.721.1km

And I am using Geotiffread

I have

ArcGIS 10 (All tools)
Matlab
ENVI

Could you please guide me?

Comment: We probably can't help you if you don't provide a link to an example TIFF from the MODIS website and the code you used to read it in.

Comment: I have added the information

Comment: According to [`imfinfo`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imfinfo.html), that TIFF file only has one layer/page in it. I think that the 7-2-1 bands are already composited (maybe just as the RGB channels, which would make extracting the bands simple). [See here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/04/02/matlab-r2009a-imread-and-multipage-tiffs/) for details on how to load multipage TIFFs in Matlab if you do end up needing that.

Comment: Hi, yes. It is composite and as RGB channels. But I am not sure how to extract them. Could you help? :(

Comment: That is why providing source code and the output/results of it here is helpful. Does `R = IMG(:,:,1);`,`G = IMG(:,:,2);`,`B = IMG(:,:,3);` not work? But I don't have any of the fancy GIS tools that you're using, so I don't actually know what `Geotiffread` gives you. You'll have to look at the documentation maybe.

Comment: @user3010024 Are you interested in a strict Matlab solution? R?

Comment: @user3010024 What is the MODIS Terra Product you are trying to process? Apparently [These](http://landweb.nascom.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/browse/single.cgi?prod=MOD09CMG&sat_ver=Terra_C5&date=2013323&proj=CMG&imgProd=MOD09CMG) are the products for day 2013323 from Terra satellite